# 'An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made' with verified certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, https

I get the following error message (which is identical every try)

> 2016-07-20 20:09:28.013 MyApp[1140:374263] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
>   2016-07-20 20:09:28.014 MyApp[1140:374263] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
>   error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x154dda750 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.com:8080/api/login, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.com:8080/api/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3})

The certificate is a validated one provided by letsencrypt. I have tested my web server configuration over and over, and everything seems to be like it should.

Running the command `openssl s_client -connect example.com:8080/api/login -tls1_2` gives all the expected results:

-It verifies the authority as `DST Root CA X3`, which is included in [Apples root CA list](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205205)

-The return is code is `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`

I have also run several ssl diagnostic tool websites such as [digicert](http://www.digicert.com), which has given no error results.

---

I can load the domain from Safari ON the iOS device, as well as chrome from my computer without having to accept "untrusted certificates".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone encounter something the same problem, ill answer my own question.
At the time of the question, Let's Encrypt (the CA of the certificate used) did not support **forward secrecy** for their https certificates (atleast not the one I got). Apple by default required this in the iOS version used at that time (I believe it was around 9.5, but I might be mistaken here).

To get around the requirement of forward secrecy, this can be specified in the Info.plist under domain exceptions.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Sometime along the road, they changed this to default land on false. I am not sure when this was, but after iOS 10.0 it was never a problem.

Comment: So where to find this file? Info.plist, I have this problem on a Joomla website when it try to play a video

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full monty if anybody is battling self-signed certs in 2023:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>YOUR-URL.COM</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```